# How do I get rid of root suckers in my yard from my neighbor's big tree?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, suckers

My neighbor has a tall very leafy tree.  The leaves are kind of heart-shaped, or larger at the top than at the bottom.  They are arranged on the stem.  I am finding little mini trees growing all over my side yard where his tree grows even though we are separated by a fence.  I try to pull them out but they are obviously rooted to his tree.  They come up between my stone sidewalks and, I'm worried that they could damage my pool.  How can I kill these root suckers growing in my yard?

Comment: Could we get a picture of the tree and the leaf to help identifying it?

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a [Quaking Aspen, *Populus tremuloides*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Populus_tremuloides), or other type of suckering tree.  You might have to dig a trench between the neighbor's tree and your yard.  It should be 18" to 2' deep.  Install metal siding or plastic vertically in the trench and backfill. Just pull up the little trees.  They won't survive, the roots won't survive without the main tree and any photosynthetic growth to make food.  You might have to do this all summer but by next year you shouldn't have a problem.

This is far easier and cheaper than using chemicals.  In fact, without the trench, chemicals wouldn't work at all.

Send pictures of the tree, of your yard and the baby trees.

Comment: Depending how close the tree is to the property line, severing all the roots along that line may lead to the tree dying. Legal but not too neighbor friendly.

Comment: Very little chance of killing the tree.  I would talk with the neighbor to let them know that there is a problem.  Anything one can do to involve the neighbor is critical.  It is our duty to make friends of our neighbors.  It would be nice to see pictures and get a better feel for things, but I've done this very thing and it worked out well.  A few times.